# irreducible representation of a symmetric group

Tags: representation-theory

Im a little confused with how to use the character table of $S_{3}$  to compute the number of number of multiplicities in $\rho$ of the irreducible complex representations of $\rho:S_{3}\rightarrow GL(Fun(H,\mathbb{C}))$. The action of $S_{3}$ on $H=X\times X\times X$ where $X=\{1,2,3\}$ given by $g(x,y,z)=(g(x),g(y),g(z))$.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: First, determine the number of fixed points of the action of every $w \in S_{3}$ on $H$, which equals the value of the character of $\rho$ at $w$. Then compute the inner product of this character and each irreducible character from the character table of $S_{3}$. These are the desired multiplicities.

Comment: I got the same character value of $\rho$  for $w$'s in the same conjugecy class. Do I need to add the values before I compute the inner product with the character values of the irreducible representation table?

Comment: Thanks I understand it now